# How can I replace strings NOT within a link tag?

Tags: php, string

I am working on this PHP function. The idea is to wrap certain words occuring in a string into certain tags (both, words and tags, given in an array). It works OK!, but when those words occur into a linked text or its 'src' attribute, then of course the link is broken and stuffed with tags, or tags that should not be inside a link are generated. This is what I have now:

```
function replace() {
  $terminos = array (
  "beneficios" => "h3",
  "valoracion" => "h2",
  "empresarios" => "h2",
  "tecnologias" => "h2",
  "...and so on..." => "etc",
  );

  foreach ($terminos as $key => $value)
  {
  $body = "string where the word empresarios should be replaced; but the word <a href='http://www.empresarios.com'>empresarios</a> should not be replaced inside <a> tags nor in the URL of their 'src' attribute.";
  $tagged = "<".$value.">".$key."</".$value.">";
  $result = str_replace($key, $tagged, $body);
  }
}
```

The function, in this example, should return `"string where the word <h2>empresarios</h2> should be replaced; but the word <a href='http://www.empresarios.com'>empresarios</a> should not be replaced inside <a> tags nor in the URL of their 'src' attribute."`

I'd like this replacement function to work all throught the string, but not inside  tags *nor* in its attributes!

(I'd like to do what is mentioned in the following thread, it's just that it's not in javascript what I need, but in PHP: `/questions/1666790/how-to-replace-text-not-within-a-specific-tag-in-javascript`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the DOM and only modify text nodes:

```
$s = "foo <a href='http://test.com'>foo</a> lorem bar ipsum foo. <a>bar</a> not a test";
echo htmlentities($s) . '<hr>';

$d = new DOMDocument;
$d->loadHTML($s);

$x = new DOMXPath($d);
$t = $x->evaluate("//text()");

$wrap = array(
    'foo' => 'h1',
    'bar' => 'h2'
);

$preg_find = '/\b(' . implode('|', array_keys($wrap)) . ')\b/';

foreach($t as $textNode) {
    if( $textNode->parentNode->tagName == "a" ) {
        continue;
    }

    $sections = preg_split( $preg_find, $textNode->nodeValue, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

    $parentNode = $textNode->parentNode;

    foreach($sections as $section) {  
        if( !isset($wrap[$section]) ) {
            $parentNode->insertBefore( $d->createTextNode($section), $textNode );
            continue;
        }

        $tagName = $wrap[$section];
        $parentNode->insertBefore( $d->createElement( $tagName, $section ), $textNode );
    }

    $parentNode->removeChild( $textNode );
}

echo htmlentities($d->saveHTML());
```

Edited to replace DOMText with DOMText and DOMElement as necessary.

Comment: Hi Adam, thank you! That was helpful, I only needed to do @$d->loadHTML($remote); in order to get rid of invalid markup messages. 

However, the problem now is that the parsing contains ASCII characters, so I get a load of them and also tags visible in the output $d->saveHTML();...

How can we get rid of that?!

Comment: I've again modified the code to search thorough each text node and replace matched strings with DOMElement objects.

Comment: well Adam, it DOES work!! The only problem now is that I am working with spanish texts. This is what I get when there are characters such as á é í ó ú ñ...:
"La Ã©tica profesional y el reducido tamaÃ±o de nuestros equipos garantizan la mÃ¡s estricta confidencialidad y discreciÃ³n de nuestros proyectos."
I have been trying different functions to encode this correctly but,  to no avail. Will post when I find a solution.
THANKS!

Comment: Also tried to preceed $s with '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />', but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To the answer you pointed, in JS, it's basically the same. You just have to specify it's a string.

```
$regexp = "/(<pre>(?:[^<](?!\/pre))*<\/pre>)|(\:\-\))/gi";
```

Also note that you may be need another preg_replace function to replace the word 'empresarios' in case it's capitalized (Empresarios) or like weird stuff (EmPreSAriOS).

Also take care of your HTML. `<h2>` are block elements and may be interpretated this way:

> string where the word empresarios
>   should be replaced;

And replaced

> string where the word
>
> ## empresarios
>
> should be replaced;

Maybe what you'll need to use is a `<big>` tag.

Comment: Thanks metrobalderas, I really did try your solution, but really, when it comes to regexp, I am such a newbie and I don't understand well what Ia m doing. Thanks anyway, probably your answer is useful for others!

Answer (score 0):

Definitely use a dom parser to isolate the qualifying text nodes before attempting to replace with a regex pattern that respects: word boundries, case-insensitivity, and unicode characters.  If you are planning to specifically target words with unicode characters, then you will need to add `mb_` to some of the string functions.

After leveraging the following insights, I tailored a solution for your scenario.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/64077957/2943403
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20675396/2943403

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/XXNkq))

```
$html = <<<HTML
foo <a href='http://test.com'>fóo</a> lórem
bár ipsum bar food foo bark. <a>bar</a> not á test
HTML;

$lookup = [
    'foo' => 'h3',
    'bar' => 'h2'
];

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$regexNeedles = [];
foreach ($lookup as $word => $tagName) {
    $regexNeedles[] = preg_quote($word, '~');
}
$pattern = '~\b(' . implode('|', $regexNeedles) . ')\b~iu' ;

foreach($xpath->query('//*[not(self::a)]/text()') as $textNode) {
    $newNodes = [];
    $hasReplacement = false;
    foreach (preg_split($pattern, $textNode->nodeValue, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE) as $fragment) {
        $fragmentLower = strtolower($fragment);
        if (isset($lookup[$fragmentLower])) {
            $hasReplacement = true;
            $a = $dom->createElement($lookup[$fragmentLower]);
            $a->nodeValue = $fragment;
            $newNodes[] = $a;
        } else {
            $newNodes[] = $dom->createTextNode($fragment);
        }
    }
    if ($hasReplacement) {
        $newFragment = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
        foreach ($newNodes as $newNode) {
            $newFragment->appendChild($newNode);
        }
        $textNode->parentNode->replaceChild($newFragment, $textNode);
    }
}
echo substr(trim(utf8_decode($dom->saveHTML($dom->documentElement))), 3, -4);
```

Output:

```
<h3>foo</h3> <a href="http://test.com">fóo</a> lórem
bár ipsum <h2>bar</h2> food <h3>foo</h3> bark. <a>bar</a> not á test
```