# Using a regular expression to replace text that is not inside hyperlink markup

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I replace strings NOT within a link tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165381/how-can-i-replace-strings-not-within-a-link-tag)

Hi is there anyone can help me with regular expression

This is the words that i want to replace

```
$text = '<a href="test-pregnancy.net">pregnancy<a> week by week, some time pregnancy can be very easy';
$search = 'pregnancy';
$replace = '<a href="google-pregnancy.net">pregnancy</a>';

print preg_replace('/('.$search.')/', $replace, $text);
```

is there any regular expression that except for words that contain inside a link? only replace words that not contain inside a link

I want it would be like this

```
$text = '<a href="test-pregnancy.net">pregnancy</a> week by week, some time <a href="test-pregnancy.net">pregnancy</a> can be very easy';
```

---

How if the condition like this.

```
$text = '<a href="test-pregnancy.net" title="welcome pregnancy people">pregnancy<a> week by week, some time pregnancy can be very easy';
```

This will also replace pregnancy in the title of href. Is there any another idea. I want a regex that using exception inside a tag.

Comment: That is some really weird sample text.

Comment: No, there is no regular expression that can do that. At least not if your HTML is much more complex than one anchor followed by some text.

Comment: Yes, that's doable. Came up before, use the search function.

Comment: @BoltClock why? because "pregnancy" is spelled correctly, but "verry" isn't? :^P

Comment: @BoltClock while you are busy, maybe we should replace the rather woman-unfriendly sample text and change "exeption" in the title to "exception" - personally, I think this post amounts to trolling though, and I don't think this question has not been answered before

Comment: @owlstead: If you find a dupe, go ahead and vote it as such. A little less work for everyone :)

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165381/how-can-i-replace-strings-not-within-a-link-tag and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044812/regex-domdocument-match-and-replace-text-not-in-a-link

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
$search =  'pregnancy';
```

with:

```
$search =  ' pregnancy ';
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use a HTML parser and find the text that is not part of an A element. See: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: -1  This would not work.

Comment: -1 Because links aren't answers. And this has been more usefully RW answered in one of the hundred duplicates.